# List generation from list containing lists using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I am having difficulties formatting the title of this question. But I think an example will make things clearer.

I have the following list containing a variable amount of other lists which contains a variable amount of 'a' objects.

```
[
    [ a, a, a, a],
    [ a, a, a],
    [ a, a, a],
    [ a, a, a, a],
    [ a, a, a],
    [ a, a, a, a],
    [ a, a, a]
]
```

in which 'a' represents an instance of the class:

```
class a {
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public SomeClass SomeClass { get; set; }
}
```

Basically what I want is create a list of `SomeClass` objects when `Number` is equal to 1.

I've achieved this using foreach loops but I'd like to achieve this using Linq.

Pseudocode code using foreach loops:

```
List<SomeObject> someObjectsList = new List<SomeObject>();

// list is the list which contains lists of 'a' objects described above in the question
foreach (var listOfAObjects in list)
{
    var listThatCompliesWithWhereClause = listOfAObjects.Where(x => x.Number == 1);

    foreach (var a in listThatCompliesWithWhereClause)
    {
        someObjectsList.Add(a.SomeObject);
    }
}

// someObjectsList is now filled with what I need
```

How could I solve this with Linq?

Also, suggestions for a better title are also welcome.

Comment: Just to check the logic is to flatten all the `a` into a single list, filter out the one with `Number` 1 and then return the `SomeClass` from in those objects?

Comment: Your loops seems to be wrong, you access `list` twice instead of `listOfAObjects`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try

```
list.SelectMany(it => it).Where(it => it.Number == 1).Select(it => it.SomeClass)
```

Answer (score 3):

You're accessing `list` twice which I believe is a typo.

The exact equivalent of your approach using LINQ is as follows:

```
var resultSet  = 
    list.SelectMany(listOfAObjects => listOfAObjects.Where(x => x.Volgnummer == 1))
        .Select(a => a.SomeObject)
        .ToList();
```

This uses `SelectMany` to collapse all the nested `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>` to a `IEnumerable<T>` where `T` is the type of elements contained in `listOfAObjects` which we then project to a `IEnumerable<R>` with the `Select` clause and finally we then accumulate the elements into a List.